# SonarScanner for .NET in Docker - solution builds with `docker run`, but not with `docker-compose`

Tags: docker, .net-core, docker-compose, msbuild, sonarscanner

I am trying to make code analysis using SonnarScanner for .NET using docker with [nosinovacao/dotnet-sonar image](https://github.com/nosinovacao/dotnet-sonar), however, I cannot build a project using `docker-compose` while everything's fine when I use `docker run` with the same parameters.

The solution consists of several sub-solutions, it seems that MS Build has some problems with building the whole solution when `docker-compose` is used, since I'm getting `MSBUILD : error MSB1008: Only one project can be specified.` error.

When `docker run` is used there's a message `Determining projects to restore...` and then the solution is built correctly.

I don't understand what's the issue since I use exactly the same image and parameters.

Here's my working `docker run` command:

```sh
docker run -it --rm \
   --network=host \
    -v /Developer/MyProject/:/source \
    nosinovacao/dotnet-sonar:latest \
    bash -c \
        "cd source \
        && dotnet /sonar-scanner/SonarScanner.MSBuild.dll begin \
        /k:MyProjectKey /name:MyProject /version:v1.2.3 \
        /d:sonar.host.url="http://localhost:9000/" \
        && dotnet build MyProject.sln -c Release \
        && dotnet /sonar-scanner/SonarScanner.MSBuild.dll end"
```

and `docker-compose`:

```yaml
version: "3.8"
services:
  dotnetscanner:
    entrypoint: /bin/bash
    command: -c "
        cd source 
        && dotnet /sonar-scanner/SonarScanner.MSBuild.dll begin 
        /k:MyProjectKey /name:MyProject /version:v1.2.3 
        /d:sonar.host.url="http://localhost:9000/"
        && dotnet build MyProject.sln -c Release \
        && dotnet /sonar-scanner/SonarScanner.MSBuild.dll end"
    image: nosinovacao/dotnet-sonar:latest
    volumes:
      - "/Developer/MyProject/:/source"
    network_mode: host
```

The docker image uses `SonarScanner for MSBuild 5.0.4` and `MSBuild version 16.8.3+39993bd9d for .NET`.

What can I do to make the SonarScanner working with `docker-compose`?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
It seems that something is wrong with passing parameters, when I explicitly define non-existing project in `docker-compose` I'm getting:

```
dotnetscanner_1  | MSBUILD : error MSB1008: Only one project can be specified.
dotnetscanner_1  | Switch:
```

When I do the same for `docker run` the `Switch:` is not null in an error message:

```
MSBUILD : error MSB1009: Project file does not exist.
Switch: NonExistingProject.csproj
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that the multi-line arguments caused the problem.

To fix this one can either make pass `command` arguments as a single line or use the following syntax:

```sh
version: "3.8"
services:
  dotnetscanner:
    command: >
     sh -c "cd source && dotnet /sonar-scanner/SonarScanner.MSBuild.dll begin /k:ProjectKey /name:Project /version:v1.2.2 
     /d:sonar.host.url="http://localhost:9000/" 
     && dotnet build -c Release  
     && dotnet /sonar-scanner/SonarScanner.MSBuild.dll end"
    image: nosinovacao/dotnet-sonar:latest
    volumes:
      - "/Project:/source"
    network_mode: host
```